# Changing the font for "alert" in beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting

I would like to change the behaviour of `\alert` so that the text is still red but now boldfaced, say.  How can I do this?  I have Googled, but all I can find is how to change the colour, as in [Changing style of alert environment in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9637/changing-style-of-alert-environment-in-beame).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After some digging, I located the definition of `\alert` in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. The rest was easy. ;-)

EDIT: There's also a more "beamer-like" way. :-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% \renewcommand<>{\alert}[1]{\begin{alertenv}\bfseries#2#1\end{alertenv}}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\alert{Some text.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, the former `\renewcommand` didn't work for me for some reason... the latter does though!

Comment: Many thanks!  I didn't think to look in the code :(