# Shorthand overlay specifications for bold text

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays

The following MWE shows the list piece by piece and each item is alert when displayed and back to normal when the next item is displayed.

How can I add more default overlay specifications to the itemize list? Say, make the text bold and alert as it appears and return to normal when the next item is displayed?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item Apple
\item Peach
\item Plum
\item Orange
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, have a look to [Changing the font for “alert” in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46134/changing-the-font-for-alert-in-beamer) that could help.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino works like a charm, sir! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can start from [Changing the font for "alert" in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46134/changing-the-font-for-alert-in-beamer). In this answer, I provide an example in which the modifications done to the font are local just to the itemize environment. Indeed, one might want just to modify the font aspect for a particular list.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries, size=\Large}
\item Apple
\item Peach
\item Plum
\item Orange
\end{itemize}
\uncover<+>{This is another \alert<.>{alerted} text but is not more in bold, since the change has been done locally to the itemize environment.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]