# Given a list of item in Beamer how to bold and unbold item one at a time?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I want to display the following sentences one at a time in a \begin{item}

However, I want them to bold and unbold one sentence at a time.

For example, I want to display

- Hello World
- Hello Earth
- Hello Sun

The audience should see

- Hello \textbf{World}

then,

- Hello World
- Hello \textbf{Earth}

then,

- Hello World
- Hello Earth
- Hello \textbf{Sun}

and finally,

- Hello World
- Hello Earth
- Hello Sun

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you could do that by saying \setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} and then use \alert for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this question has been answered here

[Shorthand overlay specifications for bold text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76089/shorthand-overlay-specifications-for-bold-text)

But just to give a quick rundown, to get what youre looking for you would have your list written as

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
            \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black} %change the font color
            \setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} %make alerted text bold
            \item<1-> Hello \alert<+>{World}
            \item<2-> Hello \alert<+>{Earth}
            \item<3-> Hello \alert<+>{Sun}
        \end{itemize}
        \uncover<+>{} %make the list all change to unbolded
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Make sure to include the empty `\uncover` command, otherwise the last item will remain bolded.

[image]

If instead you wanted the entire line to be bolded, you could instead do it as

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}    
        \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
            \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black} %change the font color
            \setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} %make alerted text bold
            \item Hello World
            \item Hello Earth
            \item Hello Sun
        \end{itemize}
        \uncover<+>{} %make the list all change to unbolded
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hi how did you attach an animated gif

Comment: I don't actually know, that was @marmot that edited in the gif. Though i suspect it might be done using the solution described in this answer https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: @ShamisenExpert I did `convert -density 300 -delay 96 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799). If you are happy with the answer, consider accepting it (by clicking the check mark left of it) and perhaps also upvoting (which I already did).

Comment: @anthsts perfect answer!