# How to change seagull color theme alert text to non-bold

Tags: beamer, fonts, color, bold, overlays

Some beamer color themes (as seagull) define alert text as bold font.

However, sold font alerts are annoying when one uses overlay (eg: `\onslide+<2->`), because bold text takes more space than normal text, which breaks the illusion of an animation.

To change alert from normal to bold, we can use the command

```
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}
```

(see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46134/changing-the-font-for-alert-in-beamer)). Unfortunately, I was unable to revert this by using something like

```
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\normaltext}
```

I don't know if this is because this command is wrong or if it is because it can't override seagull's settings.

Does someone know a trick to set non-bold text with the `\alert` command while using seagull color theme?

Comment: you need `\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\mdseries}` or `\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\normalfont}`

Comment: Thanks @dcmst! Actually the trick was to use a separate line to set `series=` and `fg=`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `\normaltext` command, it is possible to change the series of the font with the `\mdseries` command, which sets it to medium, or with the `\normalfont` command, which sets the font series, shape and familiy to the default value.

So what you need is something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\mdseries}
\begin{document}
\alert{test} 
\end{document}
```

There is also a `\textnormal{}` macro, which is the bracketed version of `\normalfont` (as `\textmd{}` is the bracketed version of `mdseries`).