# Change color for one bullet point in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, bullets

I was wondering whether there was an easy way to change the color of a specific bullet point to the color used with the `\alert` command (because I want the entire bullet highlighted as an alert).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\item<alert@2>` as per  [The Beamer class User Guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: Since I don't use a normal beamer theme, how do I specify the color as part of my theme?

Comment: To change the color of all your alerted texts, you set the color in the preambule, e.g., `\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green!80!}`. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9637/135836) for more examples.

Comment: I did that and the text is colored correctly, but the bullet point itself ist still wrong.